# is it possible to send a mail without being logged in?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

If we have a program that is used to send a mail to store information on a popular mailbox such as gmail, hotmail etc. is it possible without hardcoding the password to send a mail to itself as a logg(a text file basically)??

Since i don't have my own website or host or anything similar, i thought that using a free mailbox to save some sensor logg history to a mail adress would be easy enough.

so the main principle would be basically to send to myself a mail containing the logg and that works great. But is it possible to avoid hardcoding the password into the client? So if i want to send the log to the mail, could we possibly send it to my mail with an unknown source(it's fully okay if it would go to the trash). As it looks now, i have to enter the hardcoded credentials into the program and then send to myself, otherwise it wont get it :(

Comment: Use default credentials.  You need to create a POP email account for the user in Control Panel on the machine.  Then the password is sent encrypted to the mail server so you do not need to include the password when logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create your own stmp server and connect it to your own e-mail. If you want to stay anonymous per se, you can use a temp mail.

C# xample can be found here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sending-email-with-C-Sharp-using-smtp-servers/

You can, however, use almost any programming language to make an stmp server.

Comment: You will only be able to send locally and not to any email in the world (like GMAIL account).  To send to any mail address you need to login into a real email server.